# Remove duplicates from view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view (i don't have access to modify it, it uses UNION ALL, so i need to filter it) with this data:

| name | month | date | rating | plan_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 202201 | 2021-11-19 | 21 | 1000 |
| Second | 202201 | 2021-11-19 | 10 | 500 |
| First | 202201 | 2021-11-19 | NULL | 1000 |
| Third | 202201 | 2021-11-19 | NULL | 3000 |

I need to remove 3rd because it copies 1st row but without information about rating and i dont need to group it. How can I left only these rows with WHERE clause?

| name | month | date | rating | plan_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 202201 | 2021-11-19 | 21 | 1000 |
| Second | 202201 | 2021-11-19 | 10 | 500 |
| Third | 202201 | 2021-11-19 | NULL | 3000 |

I can't run `where rating is null` because then 4th row will dissappear.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
  month,
  date,
  rating,
  plan_sum
FROM table
ORDER BY name, month, date, rating
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension that makes sure that returns one row.
`order by` should also be used to separate duplicates with null values